# Regex (php) to extract only numbers or only letters inside square brackets (excluding the brackets)

Tags: regex

I have this regex that extracts anything inside braquets:
`[^[\]]+(?=])`

1) I want to extract the content within the brackets as a whole if it contains letters only (a-z)

2) I want to extract the content within the brackets as a whole if it contains numbers only (0-9)

So, I need 2 regex.

Comment: (?<=\[)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\]) and (?<=\[)[0-9]+(?=\]) – Tim007 - solution works!

Comment: \b[a-zA-Z]+(?=\]) and  \b[0-9]+(?=\])  will work in Javascript – Tim007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in JavaScript to get the same result.

```
var str = "Lorem [123] ipsum [dolor] sit [123dolor] amet.";
var re = new RegExp(/(?:\[)(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)(?=\])/g);
var result = [];
var myArray;
while ((myArray = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  result.push(myArray[1]);
}
console.log(result); // ["123", "dolor"]
```

Comment: Your pattern matches `[ab___cE^^[][\\\\][][]][]`. https://regex101.com/r/pG2rB8/1

Comment: (?:\[)(\d+|[a-z**A-Z**]+)(?=\])

Comment: Thanks @Tim007. Corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
(?<=\[)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cR0sC4/2)

```
(?<=\[)[0-9]+(?=\])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG9xS2/2)

Comment: Thank you, I got those already but it includes  the brackets, I need the brackets to be excluded.

Comment: `(?<=\[)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\])` and `(?<=\[)[0-9]+(?=\])`

Comment: follow up question, what would it be to work in Javascript?

Comment: `(?<=\[)` Lookbehind is not available in Javascript

Comment: Yes but if I drop it, then I am back to the result I got from my first Regex (does not discriminate between letters and numbers)

Comment: `\b[a-zA-Z]+(?=\])` or `\b[0-9]+(?=\])` : ) will work in Javascript https://regex101.com/r/dW8vL8/1

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again!